# What is the 'lang' attribute of the <html> tag used for?

Tags: html

In HTML, it's good to have a `lang` attribute in `<html>`, e.g. `<html lang="en">`.

How is this useful?

If this is used for translation, even if the language is set to English and there are all Chinese text in the document *Google Translate* detects it as Chinese, not English *(this means Google ignores the `lang` attribute)*.

Comment: The fact that Google correctly guesses what you messed up is only indicative of their superior algorithm. Nothing else.

Comment: When a search engine is asked to provide "only results in English", it will not give results that have this tag set to something other than `"en"`.

Comment: It was inappropriate to close this as off-topic. It is a genuine and relevant question (perhaps not optimally formulated, but still) about the effect of an attribute.

Comment: FYI: Jquery and Youtube sites are using the `lang` attribute in `html` tag, but this Stackoverflow site does not use it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am quoting this from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations):

> [**Declaring language in HTML**](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)
>
> Always use a language attribute on the `html` tag to declare the default language of the text in the page. When the page contains content in another language, add a language attribute to an element surrounding that content.
>
> Use the `lang` attribute for pages served as HTML, and the `xml:lang` attribute for pages served as XML. For XHTML 1.x and HTML5 polyglot documents, use both together.
>
> Use language tags from the *[IANA Language Subtag Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry)*.

Also a good read is *[Why use the language attribute?](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why.en)*.

Comment: +1 for "Why use the language attribute" link. Much better than my explanation.

Comment: Bleh... the quoted content, which is simply an unexplained instruction to use the attribute, doesn't even remotely answer the question (which was WHY to use the attribute and what it does). This is effectively a link-only answer; the only content that's actually relevant to the question is at the 'Why use the language attribute?' link. I'll probably edit this later to shift the actually relevant content into the answer (or feel free to do so yourself).

Answer (score 11):

You asked "how is this useful".

> "The `<lang=>` attribute can be used to declare the language of a Web
> page or a portion of a Web page. This is meant to assist search engine
> spiders, page formatting and screen reader technology"

Source: http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/langtag.html ([Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161122070120/http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/langtag.html))

No mention of translation - but often a search engine spider will not want to parse through a document "in the wrong language" - its index file will grow (lots of new words), and the results will not be useful to the user (who cannot read the language, and who is using the wrong search terms).

The advent of smart translation technology (like Google's, referred to above) means that some search engines can see a page in one language, translate it, and figure out that someone searching for "cow" may be interested in this page that mentions "vache" and has `<lang="fr">`.

Answer (score 8):

The `lang` attribute is needed by screen readers to let them pronounce words correctly, and also (perhaps surprisingly) sometimes needed to allow text to be *rendered* correctly by the browser.

### `lang` needed for speech synthesis

Some blind or visually impaired people use speech-synthesizing [screen readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) that speak the words on the screen. Since two words from different languages that are spelt identically may be pronounced differently, such speech synthesis cannot be done without knowing the language of the text. For instance, the word [*"pain"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pain#English) in English is pronounced completely differently to the word [*"pain"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pain#French) in French, so a screen reader that doesn't know whether it's reading English or French won't know how to pronounce *"pain"*.

Using the `lang` attribute indicates to a screen reader what language some text is in and thus allows it to pronounce the word correctly.

I recorded a demonstration of this using Narrator, the built-in screen reader for Windows. (If you'd like to reproduce this, do note that you'll need to have both the English and French voice packages installed via the *Speech* settings page in the Windows *Settings* app, and have English as your default voice.) The demo uses a HTML page with the following content:

```
<h5>No lang specified:</h5>
<p>J'aime le pain</p>

<h5>French:</h5>
<p lang="fr">J'aime le pain</p>
```

As you can hear in the recording I uploaded at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J1I65sn1CQ, Microsoft George (the default English voice) butchers the pronunciation of the French phrase (pronouncing it "Jay aim le payne"), whereas Microsoft Hortense (the default French voice) pronounces it correctly.

### `lang` needed for text rendering

Perhaps surprisingly, the benefits of the `lang` attribute are *not* limited to disabled people using speech-synthesizing assistive tech. Setting `lang` can also affect text rendering, since the correct way to render some text can be language-dependent.

There are a couple of different mechanisms by which the `lang` you set can affect how text gets rendered:

- different fonts being selected based on the `lang` attribute, either:

  - based on the browser's default font selection rules, or
  - because you've explicitly set up language-specific fonts using [`:lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) selectors in your CSS

  or
- fonts having language-specific rules included in them, such as language-specific alternative glyphs or language-specific rules about which sequences of characters to substitute with a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing))

Below I will present a couple of interesting examples I could discover of such language-specific rendering happening.

##### Language-dependent forms of Han characters

There exist many Han (Chinese) characters that have been adopted in other east-Asian languages, such as Japanese (where such characters are called "[Kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji)"). The proper way to draw these characters sometimes differs between Chinese and the other languages that have assimilated them, yet, due to Unicode's [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification), there only exists a single Unicode code point to represent the character, rather than a distinct code point for each language-specific variant of it. Several examples are listed in the [Examples of language-dependent glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language-dependent_glyphs) section of the Wikipedia article linked above.

When rendering such a character, in order to know which glyph to display (for instance, whether to display the Japanese Kanji or the Chinese hanzi), the browser needs to know the language of the text in which the character appears.

To try to see your browser considering text's language in this way, save the following HTML to a file and open it in your browser:

```
Chinese: <span lang="zh">飴</span>
<br>
Japanese: <span lang="ja">飴</span>
```

Note that the same character, `飴`, is used in both `span`s. But they display differently in the browser, at least in Chrome on my Windows PC:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the point above]

As you can see, the Kanji rendered in the span marked as Japanese is different in several ways from the hanzi rendered in the span marked as Chinese. By inspecting each span in the Chrome dev tools and looking at the "Rendered Fonts" section, I can see that this is because Chrome has used different fonts for the two spans - namely Microsoft YaHei for the Chinese span and Yu Gothic for the Japanese one.

##### `fi` ligatures getting disabled for Turkish text

As described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)#Stylistic_ligatures, a stylistic ligature is used in many fonts that merges together the letters *fi* into a single combined glyph, where the top-right corner of the *f* merges with the dot above the *i*. In most languages, like English, this looks pretty and doesn't make the text any less readable.

[image: Image showing the combined "fi" glyph]

However, such a ligature is problematic in Turkish or other languages where the [dotted and dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) both exist and are distinct characters, because it makes it impossible to tell whether it represents *fi* (an *f* followed by a dotted *i*) or *fı* (an *f* followed by a dotless *ı*).

For that reason, fonts that include a substitution of *fi* with such a ligature will hopefully have that substitution only occur in languages for which it's appropriate. As I understand it, in OpenType, such rules are implemented by making "features" in the font specific to particular "language systems" via the [Language System Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/opentype/spec/chapter2#language-system-table).

To see this in action, I downloaded a font with such a *fi* ligature - specifically [Okta Neue](https://www.dafontfree.io/download/okta-neue/) - and created the following demo page:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: oktaneue;
        src: url("Groteskly Yours - Okta Neue UltraLight.otf");
    }
    * {
        font-family: oktaneue;
    }
</style>
<span lang="en">Lütfiye</span>
<br>
<span lang="tr">Lütfiye</span>
```

Note that this time - unlike in the earlier example with hanzi and Kanji - both spans *are* using the same font. But, because *the font itself* contains language-specific features, the spans nonetheless render differently:

[image: Screenshot of the aforementioned example page]

As you can see, the *fi* ligature gets used for the span labelled as English, but not for the one labelled as Turkish - which is what we wanted!

Answer (score 2):

The `lang` attribute tells the client what language the document (or part of document) is written in. This is useful for any software which cares about language.

A key use is for accessibility. It is mentioned in [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/language-of-page.html):

> This Success Criterion helps:
>
> - people who use screen readers or other technologies that convert text into synthetic speech;
> - people who find it difficult to read written material with fluency and accuracy, such as recognizing characters and alphabets or decoding
>     words;
> - people with certain cognitive, language and learning disabilities who use text-to-speech software
> - people who rely on captions for synchronized media.

[Adrian Roselli](https://adrianroselli.com/2015/01/on-use-of-lang-attribute.html) describes some benefits:

> **Hyphens**
>
> By using lang, you get the benefits of hyphen support in your (modern)
>   browser that you otherwise would not get (assuming you use hyphens:
>   auto in your CSS).
>
> **Accessibility**
>
> At the very least, lang is a benefit for screen reader users,
>   particularly when your users don’t have the same primary language as
>   your site. It allows proper pronunciation and inflection when the page
>   is spoken.

… as well as referencing WCAG and pointing at [this document from the W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why) which lists benefits such as being able to write CSS which styles elements based on the language they are written in (so different fonts can be used for different languages), automatically selecting fonts with the right version of a glyph for a language, to aid search engines, spell checks and translation tools, to help speech synthesizers and Braille translators, and for custom scripting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, for a single-language website (hopefully you can surmise its utility for multi-language websites), the only real, actual, tangible use is that it makes the '[hyphens](http://w3.org/tr/css-text-3/#hyphens-property)' CSS property work as expected... which is not much, but more than nothing. (I'm afraid I haven't actually tested this in a browser, however, which is something we should all do to know things *for sure*.)

Via: http://blog.adrianroselli.com/2015/01/on-use-of-lang-attribute.html (which is also full of irrelevant "reasons" to use it, save that mentioned).

Comment: Tested--Firefox stable as of writing does indeed require it for the 'hyphens' property.

Comment: Passing a WCAG checkpoint is not an "irrelevant" reason. It is one the things that stands between you and an accessibility lawsuit. Also, I think you assume all single-language sites are English (or Western). It has a huge impact for font selection in Korean / Japanese sites that is political/legal, not aesthetic. So, yeah, legal impact there too.

Comment: @aardrian: Of course it is. There is no website that is accessible except for not utilizing the lang attribute / there is no website that is accessible only because it has utilized the lang attribute.

Comment: I do not disagree that there is no we web site (unproveable blanket statement notwithstanding) that is accessible simply because it added a `lang`, though some may have passed WCAG 2.0 AA as a result or become far more usable. I do, however, disagree that legal risk, political impact, and usability are irrelevant.

Comment: You're suggesting following useless laws has a use? I disagree. :) Beyond that, there are other ways to specify the default language, though absolutely none of them actually guarantee the page will be in that language. What's simpler: assuming a box marked 'oranges' is full of delicious citrus, or being able to actually identify an orange? Now nevermind simplicity—which will actually work out for a person in reality?

Comment: I think you just said it is pointless to follow the ADA. And that you think it is useless. Not much left to say here.

Comment: I'm suggesting that if adding the lang attribute does nothing tangible, that it is useless. It turns out it does have one useful side effect, though, making the 'hyphens' property work.

Comment: *"hopefully you can surmise its utility for multi-language websites"* - err, nope. What extra benefit is there for multi-language websites?

Comment: @MarkAmery Merely the actual simple purpose of the 'lang' attribute: to explicitly specify a language. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik But why does that have utility on multi-language websites if, as you assert, it lacks utility on single-language websites? What *effect* does it have, and why would that effect be something we care about on a multi-language website yet are happy to live without on a single-language one?

Comment: @MarkAmery There are no languages to distinguish on a single language website. If the primary language of a website is unintelligible to you, it's not going to matter what language that is. This among other reasons.

Comment: There really are substantial effects to setting the `lang` attribute that go well beyond its impact on the `hyphens` CSS property, which I outline in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70552130/1709587, none of which are specific to multi-language websites. In particular, for users reliant on screen-readers, it would seem that setting `lang` can be the difference between a page being read out correctly or being incomprehensible nonsense.

Comment: @MarkAmery I can't say I or anyone should care about screen readers. HTML is a plain text semantic markup language that is easily read by text to speech software, especially if you start with a text only user agent, but a "screen reader" that isn't terrible would have no trouble either (whether a language was specified or not). Screen readers are backwards hacks that make no sense (screens for the blind, for example?), and frequently cost exploitative sums for the misled privilege of using them. JAWS can be $1,000 (& still backwards). eSpeak and similar are gratis & sensible.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik complete nonsense. Both the major commercial operating systems come with screenreaders now - nobody is paying "exploitative sums" unless they truly prefer one of the standalone commercial screen readers for some reason. I have no idea how you envisage a blind person using a computer with only `espeak` to speak the content from a file or pipe, with no document navigation, no ability to navigate a GUI, and little ability to even handle interactive prompts from CLI commands. And ... [1/3]

Comment: ... [2/3] despite your recommendation of it, it does strictly worse at handling `<p lang="fr">J'aime le pain</p>` (when reading in `-m` mode to support HTML) than Windows Narrator does; it calls out that the language is French but does not switch voices, instead continuing with the default voice (English, in my case). The only way to make it pronounce French properly is to pass a command-line flag telling it to use the French voice for _everything_; mixed-language texts are simply not supported, while Narrator handles them cleanly. Orca, the screen reader built into Ubuntu, is equally useless.

Comment: [3/3] This is sadly indicative of the quality of other speech synthesis tools for Linux. They're all garbage; the voices are grating and hard to understand, Orca often misses changes to window content and doesn't read them, and whole sections of Unicode are unsupported, with tools instead listing their *codepoint numbers* one by one (try reading "Unicode  and  text" with `espeak` to see what I mean. Maybe someone will do the substantial work needed to improve this one day. But right now, only Windows or macOS are even remotely usable by blind people - via screen readers!

Comment: Well I've had a blind person recommend eSpeak, so that's you & he nulled out & me still voting screen readers are innately backwards. An informal poll I know. As for lang, it doesn't have much real usage in that form (`<p lang="foo">``). The voice switching deficiency with eSpeak would likely be *incredibly* trivial to rectify. Win & macOS, like JAWS, cost more (& not just up-front), so it's no surprise more was put to pleasant sounds. Pick your poison. I say a better future for blind people & co is far more efficiently achieved via the reading of text instead of the interpretation of visuals.

Answer (score -3):

The difference between `lang` and custom attributes is that `lang` is inherited, so even a child element of an element with attribute `lang=en` can be selected with the selector `div:lang(en){}`.