# <?php language_attributes(); ?> on html tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying (really hard) to understand what I do in wordpress (I am newbie coding). And I am having a problem just at the start.

ON the header.php I've seen:

[image]

But I don't understand why it is better to add it or what it does. I have checked it on wordpress codex and my understanding is now even worse!

Description: Displays the language attributes for the  tag. The possible language attributes are dir (text direction), lang and xml:lang. The choice of lang and xml:lang depends on the $doctype argument.

So, what does it do? why is it better to use? do I have to set language_attributes function anywhere? Can someone explain it as they were explaining it to a child?

Thank you, it is really stressing me!!

Answer (score 4):

`<?php language_attributes(); ?>` adds the `lang="en"` attribute to your html element. This is used to indicate (e.g. for google) in which language the content of your page is.

See [What is lang attribute of the <html> tag used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649798/what-is-lang-attribute-of-the-html-tag-used-for)

It also adds the `dir=""` attribute to your html, which idicates, if the text on your page is written from left to right (e.g. english, german, french, etc...) or from right to left (e.g. arabic, etc..)

Comment: but.... then it is not very important or necessary, is it? So from here I understood it is why when my dad (in Spain) accesses to an english site, google asks if he wants to translate the page in spanish, so if the file does not have this language_attributes it won't do it, right? 
So for who would be useful to add this? for the developer? for the user? for the browser? :S :S I mean, (for example) if a page that I access is in arabic..I'll see it is in arabic when I open it, right? So it will be better if I can translate it to my lang but it won't have any difference on the site itself.. no?

Comment: @eve_mf  No, it's not neccessary. But it also doesn't hurt if you add it to your page, so Google (and also e.g. screen readers for e.g. blind people) knows, in what language your content is (altough Google may use its own algorithm to determine the language of the content).

But ommiting the language tag won't stop google from asking you, if you want to translate the page, because as I state above, Google most certainly uses his own algorithm.

Comment: For us as human beeings, this tag is not very relevant (unless you are e.g. visually impaired). It's for the software that accesses your web page (search engines, screen readers, etc..) so they know, what language they should expect.

Comment: The dir-Attribute on the other hand is relevant for the browser. It tells it if it should display the text on your page left-to-right (**ltr**) or right-to-left (**rtl**)
See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_dir