# JS document.write not printing

Tags: javascript

This is a code that I'm using to practice. The prompt line works. However, nothing gets printed into the browser when I run it on both chrome and firefox. I've also tried using `<br>` instead of `<br/>` with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 2, Example 5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var greetingString = "Hello";
        var MyName = prompt("Please enter your name");
        var concatString;

        document.write(greetingString + " " + myName + "<br/>");

        concatString = greetingString + " " + myName;

        document.write(concatString);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As others have mentioned about the book, it is using some dated terminology such as `.bgColor`. However, I checked and neither `document.write()` or `<br>` is depreciated.

Comment: `myName` and `MyName` are two different symbols.

Comment: You may want to consider a more modern learning source such as code academy. I don't think anyone uses document.write anymore. Also, check your js console for errors. It looks like `myName` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. Is the use of `<br/>` or `<br>` recommended? Also, do most modern webpages include the `lang="en"` in the html section?

Comment: Please take a look in the browser console (by pressing F12). All the errors are reported there.

Comment: As for the `<br/>` question: [HTML 5: Is it <br>, <br/>, or <br />?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1946426/4642212). As for the `lang="en"` question: it’s better for semantics and SEO to have it. See [What is lang attribute of the <html> tag used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14649798/4642212). All your questions are already answered elsewhere.

Comment: @dlsso I have already finished the JS coarse at codecademy and was looking in finishing an actual book (Beginning JavaScript 5th ed.).

Comment: If that book teaches you to use `document.write`, then it’s better used for Christmas — inside the fireplace. Please refer to more up-to-date tutorial sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web) instead.

Comment: @James if you've already done the web basics and JS tracks you can probably learn the most just by picking a project and building it, googling when you run into something you don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"var MyName`"

to `"var myName"`.

These 2 things are different since Javascript is case sensitive