# HTML lang attribute: what is the role of the locale?

Tags: html, locale, lang

I am aware of the role of the `lang` attribute as indicating to relevant software the language of the page or section.

Some languages also include the possibility of a locale. In my case it would be something like `<html lang="en-au">` to indicate English in Australia.

I have read:

[What is lang attribute of the <html> tag used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649798/what-is-lang-attribute-of-the-html-tag-used-for)

but it doesn’t mention **locale** at all, let alone explain it.

The question is, how is the locale used, if at all?

Comment: Intresting question it inspired me to find this : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2005/02/17/the-differences-between-locales-and-languages/

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, this, for example:

```
<input type="date" lang="en-AU" />
```

will configure the input to show dates in the way it is acceptable in Australia.  Which is different from, say, Canada that also uses English.

And that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

W3C spec on language and locale identifiers: https://www.w3.org/TR/ltli/

IETF spec on the make up of the attribute: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt

It's system / platform / OS / user specific and based on what technology / language you're using, there are ways to determine it and it's usage.

For e.g.

apple / iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html

Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmbx.html